# Can I make STATICFILES_DIR same as STATIC_ROOT in Django 1.3?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-staticfiles

I'm using Django 1.3 and I realize it has a **collectstatic** command to collect static files into **STATIC_ROOT**. Here I have some other global files that need to be served using **STATICFILES_DIR**.

Can I make them use the same dir ?

Thanks.

Comment: [Please folllow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161271/can-i-make-staticfiles-dir-same-as-static-root-in-django-1-3) - I have found the answer from stackoverflow

Answer (score 93, accepted):

No. In fact, the file `django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py` even checks for this and raises an `ImproperlyConfigured` exception when you do so:

> "The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting"

The `STATICFILES_DIRS` can contain other directories (not necessarily app directories) with static files and these static files will be collected into your `STATIC_ROOT` when you run *collectstatic*. These static files will then be served by your web server and they will be served from your `STATIC_ROOT`.

If you have files currently in your `STATIC_ROOT` that you wish to serve then you need to move these to a different directory and put that other directory in `STATICFILES_DIRS`. Your `STATIC_ROOT` directory should be empty and all static files should be collected into that directory (i.e., it should not already contain static files).

Comment: so where can I put the static files that belong to the website, but not to a specific app?

Comment: That exception only happens when launching django manually. When configured with an Apache server for example, it works like a charm. It also seems correct to me because all the admin files are collected under `static/admin/`. Are there any potential problem that could happen doing so?