# Django debug-toolbar - Can't make it work (ImproperlyConfigured: The STATICFILES_DIRS ...)

Tags: python, django, boto

The error (when running the django runserver command):

> ImproperlyConfigured: The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting

I don't really use django static (this is mostly and api server) and I just want django debug to debug and `explain` my sql queries. So what I have is:

```
STATIC_DIRECTORY = '/'
    MEDIA_DIRECTORY = '/media/'
    STATIC_URL = S3_URL + STATIC_DIRECTORY
    MEDIA_URL = S3_URL + MEDIA_DIRECTORY

    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'server.s3utils.StaticRootS3BotoStorage'
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'server.s3utils.MediaRootS3BotoStorage'


STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'

    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        abs_path('staticfiles'),
        # ABS_PATH('/static/'),  #D either
    )oesn't work either
    )
```

**EDIT:** If I just remove `STATICFILES_DIRS` the errors changes:

> TypeError at /admin/ Error when calling the metaclass bases
>       function() argument 1 must be code, not str Request Method:   GET Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/ Django Version:    1.6.2
>   Exception Type:   TypeError Exception Value:   Error when calling the
>   metaclass bases
>       function() argument 1 must be code, not str

I also tried as one of the answers suggested to add

```
 if settings.DEBUG:
     import debug_toolbar
     urlpatterns += patterns('',
         url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
     )
```

Doesn't help..

I guess that I'm missing something very simple (but annoying) I'll be glad for help with this.

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161271/can-i-make-staticfiles-dir-same-as-static-root-in-django-1-3? Also try DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PATCH_SETTINGS = False

Answer (score 8):

Django debug toolbar chokes when using S3BotoStorage. I mostly wanted SQL logging, so adding this code to settings.py to disable the StaticFilesPanel was a workaround for me:

```
DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS = [
 'debug_toolbar.panels.versions.VersionsPanel',
 'debug_toolbar.panels.timer.TimerPanel',
 'debug_toolbar.panels.settings.SettingsPanel',
 'debug_toolbar.panels.headers.HeadersPanel',
 'debug_toolbar.panels.request.RequestPanel',
 'debug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLPanel',
 # 'debug_toolbar.panels.staticfiles.StaticFilesPanel',                                                                                                                                    
 'debug_toolbar.panels.templates.TemplatesPanel',
 'debug_toolbar.panels.cache.CachePanel',
 'debug_toolbar.panels.signals.SignalsPanel',
 'debug_toolbar.panels.logging.LoggingPanel',
 'debug_toolbar.panels.redirects.RedirectsPanel',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This [django-debug-toolbar explicit-setup](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/installation.html#explicit-setup)
Says something about:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, patterns, url

if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    )
```

Have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered the same error when I created custom storage using lambda:

```
StaticRootS3BotoStorage = lambda: S3Boto3Storage(bucket_name='example-name')
```

Changing it to class solved the problem:

```
class StaticRootS3BotoStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    bucket_name='example-name'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install django-debug-toolbar
```

check your settings.py file :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'debug_toolbar',


...

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware",
    ...
]

...

INTERNAL_IPS = [
    "127.0.0.1",
]
...

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),
)
```

urls.py

```
path("__debug__/", include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
```

And run this command : `python manage.py collectstatic`