# The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, collectstatic, django-static

I'm using Django 1.7. When deploying my site to a Production server and running `collectstatic`, I get following error message:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting

I use split settings; my production `local.py` contains:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/username/projects/site/static/'
```

and my `base.py` contains:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I make STATICFILES\_DIR same as STATIC\_ROOT in Django 1.3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161271/can-i-make-staticfiles-dir-same-as-static-root-in-django-1-3)

Comment: Possible, but searching "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting" in Google didn't point me to that one.

Comment: That's because you had quotes around it. That question is regarding the same problem.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/staticfiles/), collectstatic will copy the files from various folders into STATIC_ROOT.

Therefore, you cannot use the `STATIC_ROOT` folder in `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

Solution: change `STATIC_ROOT` to e.g. `STATIC_ROOT = '/home/username/projects/site/assets/'`

Comment: The 'docs' link for Django 1.7 is no longer live, but it works if you increase the Django version number in there from 1.7 to 3.2: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

Answer (score 39):

I know it is an old post but this solution has worked for me and might help someone else.

In settings.py:

```
    if DEBUG:
        STATICFILES_DIRS = [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
       ]
    else:
        STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I don't think this will interact well with collectstatic?

Answer (score 29):

I faced same error like this `(staticfiles.E002) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting.` when i try to use compressor

Main problem is My settings.py file

`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
 STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]`

Remove or comment :

`STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]`

Comment: then how do you serve static files from the development server? (via `python manage.py runserver`)

Comment: will run into the error:     raise ImproperlyConfigured("You're using the staticfiles app "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.

Comment: @Eric it is advised to set `STATIC_ROOT` to say `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'var', 'static')` that directory will contain staticfiles copied by django if you execute `collectstatic` command. That command will look for static files in `STATICFILES_DIRS` and if you run `runserver`, then it will serve your static files from `STATICFILES_DIRS` .

Answer (score 4):

The solution is that the STATIC_ROOT must not be set if you are running the Django development server:

```py
import sys
if sys.argv[1] != 'runserver':
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

Tested with Django 2.1 in a Windows 10 development environment and in an Ubuntu 18.04 docker container on AWS in a production environment.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error below:

> The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting.

Because I set the same folder `static` to [STATIC_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#std-setting-STATIC_ROOT) and [STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs) as shown below:

```py
# "settings.py"

STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static/'
]
```

So, I set the different folder `staticfiles` to `STATIC_ROOT` as shown below, then the error was solved:

```py
# "settings.py"

STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles/' # Here
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static/'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

in settings.py set static root to virtual environment so that it collects the static files to folder static_in_env

```
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(VENV_PATH,'static_in_env/')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to enter complete path of static directory:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/reza/blog/static/'
```

Or If you want to use Collects the static files into **STATIC_ROOT** by `django-admin collectstatic` command you have to use :

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in pythonanywhere, added:

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/user/project/'
```

Then run:

```py
python3.9 manage.py collectstatic
```

It kind of worked, but sent the files in the main directory...

Answer (score 0):

For pythonaywhere:

1 - Add your static root in the setting.py

[image]

2 - Update manually the path environment into web app configuration

[image]

Answer (score -4):

saw this in [Django 1.11 documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/)

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Once you make changes to the urls.py as shown above, it should work fine.

Comment: this is not suitable for production. the workaround is only used for local development!