# I am trying to host my Django project in heroku, but i am getting an error when i am collecting static files with python manage.py collectstatic

Tags: django, static

I am trying to host my Django project in heroku, but i am getting an error when i am collecting static files with python manage.py collectstatic.

I have looked for this file **'plugins/flot/jquery.flot.js.map'** in my plugin folder, but i can't find it anywhere.

**whitenoise.storage.MissingFileError: The file 'plugins/flot/jquery.flot.js.map' could not be found with <whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0x000001BE271A1810>**

I tried running python manage.py collectstatic, reconfigure the manifestfile in the settings.py, but no solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/38954680/16770846