# Django, serving static files

Tags: python, django

I have multiple apps and each of them has static file.
And also I want to add some global static file like jQuery.

My project structure is like

```
--mysite

  |------app1

     |-----static

  |------app2

     |-----static

  |------app3

     |-----static


  |------media
  |------static    (global one)

     |-----app1
     |-----app2
     |-----app3
```

my setting file is like

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

and url file is like

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', 'home.views.index'),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^users/', include('users.urls')),
url(r'^projects/', include('cvproject.urls'))
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + \
          static(settings.STATIC_URL,     document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

I am developing the web app following the example on the Django website.

When I load static file in templates, it can only find the files in the individual directories. And how can I load the global static files?

Thank you

Comment: What is the value of TEMPLATE_LOADERS in your settings?

Comment: just fair warning this is not recommended for production servers ... it is better to use your web layer(apache/nginx/etc) to redirect `/static` to your static files directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Staticfiles will automatically look for static files in multiple locations. and this goes with "finders" ( `STATICFILES_FINDERS`).

1. `AppDirectoriesFinder` : look for "/static/" directory of your apps
2. `STATICFILES_DIRS` : the finder that is FileSystemFinder

You have these tools to work with in static files, I think you can do what you want to do with `STATICFILES_DIRS`. you can find [STATICFILES_DIRS examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS)

Comment: thank you, create a new folder and collect them into static_root works

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the FileSystemFinder included in your [`STATICFILES_FINDERS` in `settings.py`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_FINDERS)

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder'
)
```

Then define an additional dir to include additional static files in [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs) like:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Comment: The staticfiles_dirs is same as static root and returns "ImproperlyConfigured: The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting"

Comment: Change it for another folder, both should be different http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161271/can-i-make-staticfiles-dir-same-as-static-root-in-django-1-3