# Django static won't load

Tags: django, static

This is driving me crazy for the last 2 hours. Please help.
Django 1.10

**settings.py:**

```
 STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

 STATICFILES_DIRS = []

 STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**project_folder/static/images/abc.png** is working through "{ static 'images/abc.png' }"

I've just added **project_folder/static/images/def.png** but it DOES NOT work through "{ static 'images/def.png' }"

Both were tested in the same file so {% load static %} was always there.

I had also tried to copy abc.png to def.png just in case my original def.png was bad. But it's still not working.

I hope what I said make sense. Thank you for your help

Comment: `STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]` ?

Comment: did you run `python manage.py collectstatic` after adding def.png ?

Comment: STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT

Comment: I'm working on local, Debug=True so I haven't ran collectstatic. But I've just tried it now and it didn't work.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161271/can-i-make-staticfiles-dir-same-as-static-root-in-django-1-3) solved the issue for me.