# custom static files not loading in django project

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles, django-static

I have a django project where I have kept all the static files in a project level `static` directory.
I have included

`STATIC_URL = "/static/"`

`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`

in the `settings.py`. ALso I have added `+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` to the urlpatterns in the project level urls.py.

My issue is that some of the static files load whereas some do not. For. eg.  I am using `django_google_maps` and the (example url) `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/django_google_maps/js/google-maps-admin.js` loads right and the corresponding work is done.

But when I try to load my custom js/css/any-static files, (example url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/favicons/favicon.ico` or `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/image-upload-script.js`), they do not load and raise a `django.views.static.serve` error with 404 not found.
They are right there in the directory though. I see that the static files used by third party packages are loading right but not my custom ones.

What is it that I am missing? Do we require something else to load our custom js/css files??  And yes I have used `{% load static %}` in my template.

Comment: Did you use `python manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: yes I did. @BiploveLamichhane

Comment: It might be cache problem. Can you reload using shorcut: Ctrl + F5

Comment: Yes I have tried that. Also to make sure I did it in incognito but still the same problem.

Comment: As far as I know, you don't have to worry about what you are calling `custom static files`.

Comment: Are you referencing the files as {% static 'js/...' %}?

Comment: @vladthelad Yes I have  called them as, <script src="{% static 'js/image-upload-script.js' %}"></script>

Comment: ok can we try a few things? First of all, have you set MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL yet? taking a look at one of my old projects, I had the += static you wrote above with MEDIA_ROOT and URL instead of the static ones

Comment: Yes the MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL has been set and the media files are accessible.

Comment: Add folder structure and template code to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had been using static files at the project level and not the app level. Any new static file, I was directly adding to the static directory which was my static root as well. Now as per this answer,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12161409/5379191 ,

"Your STATIC_ROOT directory should be empty and all static files should be collected into that directory (i.e., it should not already contain static files)".
So, the main thing was that it should not already contain the static files.

I created a new staticfiles folder in the project level directory, shifted my custom static files to that directory, ran the collectstatic command, and then boom it worked.
So, the main thing here to remember is not to directly place your static files in the static root dircetory but rather let the collectstatic do its job.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this worked for me:

MEDIA_URL = '/static/images/'